# What TeX processor does Stacks Project use to generate HTML?

Tags: html, latex2html

Which TeX processor does [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu) use to generate HTML? (`htlatex`, `tex4ht`, etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The about page at the site you link to shows the link to a github repository for the tools used,  the main html conversion appears to be a custom python code

https://github.com/stacks/stacks-tools

with the math being left as TeX and handled in the browser by MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

See the [README](https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/blob/master/README):

> You can simply latex the files in the current directory read them, edit them, and submit your changes by email back into the project.
>
> Here is are some pointers to documentation:
>
> - how to create all dvi/pdf files at once, see documentation/make-project
> - how to submit your work, see documentation/submitting-patches
> - how to use git, see documentation/git-howto
> - read about support from organizations in documentation/support
> - for a rough todo list, see documentation/todo-list
> - for technical rules governing internal references, see documentation/rules
>
> For more information, please see the website at the address above.

The project uses apparently the [`make` routine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)), see also the [documentation](https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/blob/master/documentation/make-project) for more information about how to use `make`.

Comment: My question is not about `make` utility, it is about the actual program which transforms (fragments of) TeX source into HTML. I know that this program is (directly or indirecty) invoked by `make`, but it isn't `make` itself. So I will downvote your answer

Comment: @porton Why don't you look up the `html` source code then, which clearly has a line `src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js'` in it instead of downvoting answers of people trying to help you? I delete my answer then if this is fine for you.

Comment: @jjdb not sure why you got downvoted but actually neither the reference to make nor the mathjax link show how the main body of the html was constructed from tex: that is, what converts `\section` to `<h2>` or whatever. Unusually  the html pages don't have a meta tag giving the generation software (that was my first thought to look too)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yep, you're correct. I also misunderstood the question. It seems to me that the important conversion is in the file [functions.py](https://github.com/stacks/stacks-tools/blob/0a0b43554ba58f8c863b985f33840821d706992c/functions.py) However, there is also a sql database in the project, but I haven't quite figured the connection yet.